# SD Card interpreted as wrong size

Tags: dd, gparted, sd-card

I used `dd` to write a 2GB image to an 8GB SD card; `gparted` now sees it as a 2GB SD card and I can't figure out how to format it for 8GB again. `dd`also sees it as a 2GB SD card when trying to format it with `of=/dev/sdb if=/dev/zero bs=1M`. How can I get it to know its real size?

Comment: By copying 2GB image to flash you have overwrite its partition table. To fix it you can use fdisk: simply create new partition in free space. If you want to copy data from 2GB image to 8GB flash, then mount image through loop device and simply copy its content by cp or file manager (but then you will lose a boot record, to fix it first copy first 512 bytes of image to flash by dd).

Comment: BTW, to clear your flash you need to say `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=10M`, not `of=/dev/zero`. This will take a long time, so much simpler way is to use fdisk: remove all partitions, then create some or just format flash without creating partitions if you don't need more than one partition.

Comment: I corrected my question to fix the typo that your second comment addresses. I had used `if=/dev/zero`,just typed it wrong.

Comment: What does `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following commands:

```
cat /proc/partitions
cfdisk YOUR_DEVICE ===> such as cfdisk /dev/sdb
```

Comment: This helps, but the `cfdisk` utility doesn't seem to know that the disk is 8GB, even if `/proc/partitions` says so.

Comment: How canI make an 8GB partition?

Comment: I just had to reboot before cfdisk recognized the size of the disk, or else I had to run it as root. I'm not sure if I ran it as root before rebooting.

Comment: @Jake223, you don't need to reboot: just replug flash.

Comment: @Jake223 task of cfdisk  is manipulation of disk such add and delete partitions.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh the issue was that cfdisk wouldn't let me create a partition larger than 2GB.